# Querying nested columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table:

```
+---------------+--------------------+-------+
|       col_name|           data_type|comment|
+---------------+--------------------+-------+
|_corrupt_record|              string|   null|
|             af|              bigint|   null|
|       dst_addr|              string|   null|
|       dst_name|              string|   null|
|        endtime|              bigint|   null|
|           from|              string|   null|
|             fw|              bigint|   null|
|       group_id|              bigint|   null|
|            lts|              bigint|   null|
|         msm_id|              bigint|   null|
|       msm_name|              string|   null|
|       paris_id|              bigint|   null|
|         prb_id|              bigint|   null|
|          proto|              string|   null|
|         result|array<struct<erro...|   null|
|           size|              bigint|   null|
|       src_addr|              string|   null|
|      timestamp|              bigint|   null|
|            ttr|              double|   null|
|           type|              string|   null|
+---------------+--------------------+-------+
```

How can I make DESC show the `result` column? I wish to know how to construct queries so the columns within it can be retrieved. I don't know the structure. I am using Spark SQL to query so I don't have an interface.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark SQL, you can execute the following command.

```
describe extended databasename.tablename;
```

In the result look for schema-

```
# Detailed Table Information  CatalogTable(
       Table ...
       Owner ...
       Created...
       Lat Access ...
       Type ...
       Schema
```

However, the output schema is not formatted. If you have an extensive schema it would be better to write a small program which would format the result for you.

Command source-
[Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/describe-table.html)